# Sumar un numero a valor obtenido de consulta

Tags: django

Tengo el valor de una consulta:

```
ultimo_numero = Muestra.objects.latest('numero', '-created_at')
```

Y según un condicional quiero sumarle "1":

```
       if not obj.pk:
        if not fecha:
            obj.numero = 1
        else:
            obj.numero = ultimo_numero + 1
```

Esto me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro entender porque no funciona, busqué posibles soluciones pero no encontré nada.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estás intentando operar tipos de datos diferentes.
Puedes comprobarlo añadiendo código para escribir por consola el tipo de dato:
$ type(ultimo_numero)

Comprueba que Muestra.objects.latest('numero', '-created_at') te devuelve el tipo de dato que esperas, ya sea int o float.

Tal vez tengas que modificar esa clase, o como alternativa (si es el caso) convertir string to int con la functión int( ultimo_numero ).